# Load data of a pcap file and insert into a SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert, pcap

I have a file with extension `.pcap` and I want to INSERT all data of this file into a table in a SQL Server database.

I have tried to use `BULK INSERT` because I was using this to load `.csv` file and insert all data of csv file in a table. But now I want to load a `.pcap` file and insert data of this file into SQL Server database.

I am able to open that `.pcap` file in WireShark, but I want to load all data into a SQL Server database. Below is the code which I am trying to do this::

```
 CREATE TABLE #DataUpdation
 (
        Number BigInt
        ,Time_ VarChar(512)
        ,Source_ VarChar(512)
        ,Destination_ VarChar(512)
        ,Protocol_ VarChar(512)
        ,Length_ VarChar(512)
        ,Info VarChar(8000)
    )

    DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(Max)
    SET @Query=
     'BULK INSERT #DataUpdation
       FROM '+char(39)+'C:\Sample.pcap'+char(39)+'
       WITH
       (      
          FIELDTERMINATOR = '','',
          ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'',
          FIRSTROW = 2 ,
          MAXERRORS =0 
       )'
    EXECUTE(@Query) ;
```

Here is the error :

> Msg 4866, Level 16, State 8, Line 1
>   The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 7. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.
>
> Msg 7301, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

I have googled it to get the field terminator of `.pcap` file but no luck...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its resolved when i change ROWTERMINATOR = ''\r''.

Now the issue is that the data in sql table is not in readable form :-(

Comment: Maybe you're already aware of that, but there's been (or there _is_) a couple of open source projects, some on liberal license, that do that already and that you may want to look at, would it be only for inspiration/method or what _not_ to do. Just google around "pcap sql".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the command to convert a pCap file to csv format:

> tshark -T fields -n -r {the pathname of the capture file} -E
>   separator=, -e {first field name} -e {second field name} ... >{the
>   pathname of the output file}

Where `{the pathname of the capture file}` is the pathname of the capture file you're reading and `{first field name}, {second field name}` and so on are the names of the fields, and `{the pathname of the output file}` is the pathname of the output file.

Here is the final command of TShark to convert pCap file to CSV file format:

```
tshark -T fields -n -r C:\capture.pcap -E separator=, -e ip.src -e ip.dst >C:\output.csv
```

Now we have the pCap file in CSV format, it is now possible to Insert/Add this in sql server database table.

**Note:** *`tshark`* =  `C:\Program Files\Wireshark\tshark.exe`

Answer (score 0):

> I have googled it to get the field terminator of `.pcap` file but no luck...

There *is* no "field terminator" for pcap files, which is why you had no luck.

A pcap file has a bunch of records containing the raw packet bytes as they were transmitted on the network; it doesn't have the values you list - "Number" is just the sequence number of the packet (the first packet has 1, the second packet has 2, etc.) and the rest are the result of Wireshark or TShark parsing the raw packet bytes according to the specifications (or reverse-engineered information) for the protocols in the packet, they don't directly appear in the pcap file.

What you can do is to run TShark on the packets, capture the output columns that it prints, and process *that* data and put it into the database.

Comment: Can you please tell me the exact code which take file path of .pcap file and give me output line by line or all at once in a variable or .csv file format ?
Actually i have a asp.net web-form which takes .pcap file by Upload file and i want to process that file and dump/insert into sql database. I knew how to process .csv file or excel So if i get .pcap file output then it will be done....

Thanks in advance :-(